# Array Of ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I am a newbie to rails and i needed to execute some sql query and array output it to the view.

on conttroler

```
@accounts = Account.all
 @itemlist = Account.find(:all,:select => 'subdomain')

 @schemasize = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '}+@itemlist.map(&:subdomain).join(" ")+%q{') As bigint) )  As schema_size}).to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_f / 1024
```

output on command

```
  Account Load (36.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts"
  Account Load (2.0ms)  SELECT subdomain FROM "public"."accounts"
   (88.0ms)  select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table
_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schem
a = 'subdomain1 subdomain2') As bigint) ) As schema_size
  Rendered accounts/kapasitas.html.erb within layouts/admin (239.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2765ms (Views: 2208.1ms | ActiveRecord: 484.0ms)
```

on html.erb

```
  <tr>
    <td><%= account.subdomain %></td>
    <td><%= @schemasize %></td>
  </tr>
```

output on view : http://i.cubeupload.com/jVrShN.png

cannot schema of size per subdomain.

i want output such as : http://i.cubeupload.com/PMPBYn.png

How can I do that?
any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't bother with `pg_size_pretty`, let the display code worry about formatting.

Next, you need to understand that `select_rows` returns an array-of-arrays (one inner array for each row returned) and that the array entries will be strings.

Your query returns a single row so you can use `first` to extract that row and another `first` to extract the single column from that row. Then you can use `to_i` to get a number that the helpers will understand:

```
@schemasize = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select CAST(...)})
                                           .first
                                           .first
                                           .to_i
```

and when displaying, use [`number_to_human_size`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human_size):

```
<%= number_to_human_size(@schemasize) %>
```

See the documentation for a list of possible options for `number_to_human_size`.

If you're worried about overflow a `Fixnum` with the `to_i` call, don't. `to_i` will switch to using `Bignum` as needed:

```
1.9.2p312 :011 > '1'.to_i.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.2p312 :012 > '12345678910111213141516'.to_i.class
 => Bignum
```

and `number_to_human_size` is just as happy with `Bignum` as it is with `Fixnum`.

If you always want the results in MB then use `to_f` (or `to_d` for `BigDecimal`) instead of `to_i`, scale things by hand (as you're doing now), and use [`String#%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-25) to format it:

```
<%= '%.4f' % @schemasize %>
```

---

If you want the sizes for each schema, then you'll want to adjust your `table_schema = ...` to `table_schema in (...)` and then tack on a `GROUP BY table_schema`. Something like this:

```
select table_schema, sum(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema in ('subdomain1', 'subdomain2')
group by table_schema
```

That will give you an array of array like this from `select_rows`:

```
[
  [ 'subdomain1', '3284762389' ],
  [ 'subdomain2', '129837' ]
]
```

and then you can unpack it each row with:

```
@sizes = raw.map { |schema, size| [ schema, size.to_i ] }
# Or to_d as noted above
```

Then you can loop over `@sizes` in your ERB and format the size as above.

Comment: thx bro, but that's not what I mean, I want my query put size of schema **per subdomain** .. how to get array from my query.

Comment: @KapanjadiMomod: Ah, I see. Have a look at the bottom of my updated answer.